# Movie about two children who discover an alien stranded in an old English-style village

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I've been trying to find an old movie I saw in the past and hoping someone here might know it. Following the helpful "how to ask a good question" meta post:

- **Detail.** The story follows two young children who become aware of something otherworldly in their village. It turns out that the thing is an alien whose ship has crashed somewhere, and it is trying to find something (I don't remember what) to get its ship flying again.
- **What is it?** A movie that, from memory, was in black & white; Sci-Fi with possible light horror.
- **When was it?** I saw it in the UK back during the late 1980s or very early 1990s on TV, however, even then it felt like an old movie, so I suspect the movie itself is quite a bit older.
- **What was memorable about it?** A few memories:

  - The children were a boy and a girl. I believe the girl was played by a male actor.
  - I have a memory of the children walking down a street past houses that looked like old thatched houses in an old UK village.
  - Several scenes in the ruins of a church; the alien appeared as a flickering foggy light, about man sized but no real detail.
  - I don't think we see the alien or its spaceship in any real depth; the flickering foggy light was about the majority of what we see.
  - The movie itself didn't explain the alien and its situation particularly well.
- **What did it look like?** My memory is of a black and white movie; I remember it was likely a UK-filmed movie but of course that might be an inaccurate memory. Saw it on TV, perhaps on Channel 4?

Apologies for the lack of detail above - if anyone knows what movie this is, I'd be so delighted to finally know! I'd love to watch it again as I have no memory of how it ended.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is (possibly) [*The Watcher in the Woods*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Watcher_in_the_Woods_(1980_film)) from 1981. It was shown on British TV, as I recall watching it.

It features a lot of the elements you describe:

- Boy and girl in british village setting. Definitely scenes in and around a old church.
- It is actually in colour but its not exactly a vibrant palette.
- The alien does appear as a ball of light.
- Your final comment about the plot being vague is bang on the money, as this film suffered a lot from studio interference.

And here is the trailer on Youtube – you may be able to identify the scenes you remember:

Comment: Thank you so much! Whilst the movie didn’t look at all like I remembered, after reading Wikipedia and watching scenes of the movie online leave me believing this must be the movie I remembered - the detail of the alien is spot on! Thank you again, been periodically trying to find this for many years!